# Autofac - Dynamic Instantiation of a factory (func<>)

Tags: c#, autofac

The standard approach would be to instantiate a factory and in the implementation of the factory call Resolve(). I don't want to tie my class to the container because it seems like a bad practice.

Standard approach:

```
    T IDataRepositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<T>()
    {
        return MyProject.Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<T>();
    }
```

Instead, I am trying to use [dynamic instantiation](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b)

```
public class SomethingManager
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IRepository> repositoryFactory;

    public SomethingManager(Func<Type, IRepository> aRepositoryFactory)
    {
        repositoryFactory = aRepositoryFactory;
    }

    public void GetSomething()
    {
        var repo1 = repositoryFactory(typeof(IBlogRepository));
        var repo2 = repositoryFactory(typeof(IUserRepository));
        (...)
    }
}
```

The problem is with getting the concrete implementation. With the standard approach I could do something like this:

```
var something = repositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IBlogRepository>();
```

**With the dynamic instantiation from Autofac I can pass an interface here:**

```
var something = repositoryFactory(typeof(IBlogRepository));
```

**but I have no idea how to a properly register this in autofac.
What is the workaround or solution to this?**

Comment: The `Func<Type, IRepository>` takes a `Type` as the input parameter, so I guess you're looking for `var something = repositoryFactory(typeof(IBlogRepository))`?

Comment: Yes, that is true. The problem is that I have no idea how to register something like this in autofac to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register generic class which parameterizes factory by its own type parameter.

```
public class SomethingClient<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> somethingFactory;

    public SomethingClient(Func<T> aSomethingFactory)
    {
        somethingFactory = aSomethingFactory;
    }

    public void SomeDynamicScenario()
    {
        var something = repositoryFactory();
        //operate on new object
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomethingClient<>)).AsSelf();
```

Resolving:

Just inject `SomethingClient<SomeParticularType>` where you need it.

Comment: I do not understand how it solves the issue. I want to have the same functionality as I would have with a factory approach I presented. There are scenarios where I may need 2 or 3 different repositories in the method call of e.g SomethingManager. With the approach, you presented I see no way of how this can be done. I have changed the code in my post to be more fitting. SomethingManager can be a wcf manager class or a web api controller.

Comment: This cannot be done without container involvement. However, you don't have to reference global static something - jus inject IComponentContext instead of factory and resolve what you need from it.

Comment: Yesss, it worked! :D I have no ties to the container from my classes so I am avoiding the service locator pattern. I was trying to do exactly what is described in this article: http://jahyacode.blogspot.com/2012/03/using-autofacs-auto-factories-to-avoid.html   It's almost identical just the types of the arguments, in the example there, are different. Is it really not possible with the Func<T>? I thought that it this exact use was the whole point of its existence...

Comment: "I have no ties to the container from my classes" - well... I hate to break this to you, but actually IComponentContext **_is_** a tie to a container. :) It's just not so strong as static service locator, but still it is a part of Autofac. What you want to do is to write your own custom factory that uses IComponentContext - it will be your abstraction from particular DI container.